# GETPROFILESTRING is Crashing

Tags: vba, ms-word

The VBA code below is crashing when i run Read_Click(). But Write_Click is working.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" _
(ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any, ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Long, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WritePrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
(ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any, ByVal lpString As Any, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Sub Write_Click()
 WritePrivateProfileString "Parameters", "Autolaunch", "1", "D:\Test.ini"
End Sub

Private Sub Read_Click()
    Dim buffer As String, IniData As String
     buffer = String(255, Chr(0))
     MsgBox Left(buffer, GetPrivateProfileString("Parameters", "Autolaunch", "1", 
 buffer, Len(buffer), "D:\Test.ini"))
End Sub
```

Windows 10-X64/Office 365-X64

Comment: Can you provide a bit of detail as to what the error/issue is when you run this?

Comment: Why aren't you using `System.PrivateProfileString` that's part of the Word object model? That should be less prone to the vagaries of different versions of Windows / Word...

Comment: I need to get all keys from a sections. This is not possible using System.PrivateProfilestring() Ex: GetPrivateProfileSection(Section, RetVal, 255, Filename) –

Comment: When i run the code above word.exe closes. No message.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, what fixed it for me seems to be switching lpKeyName data type from Any to String in the GetPrivateProfileString definition:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" _
             (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
               ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
               ByVal lpDefault As String, _
               ByVal lpReturnedString As String, _
               ByVal nSize As Long, _
               ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
```